# Horizontal scroll using CSS animation - translate with sticky position not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-position, css-transforms

I have created a fiddle with infinite horizontal scroll using **CSS animation** and I want the first element in the list to be **sticky**.

It works as expected when using the `left` property in the `@keyframes` whereas it does not work when the `transform: translateX` property is used.

The reason for changing to transform is due to

1. browser performance
2. The elements inside the cards are flickering in a real-time scenario (*where I have more complex element structure inside `.card`*) which is expected to be solved by updating the code to the `transform` property.

Can anyone provide a solution for this scenario using `transform`?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroller {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  animation: autoScroll 10s linear infinite;
}
 
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
}
  
.sticky-el {
  width: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes autoScroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    //left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    //left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="card sticky-el">Sticky 1</div>
    <div class="card">Card 1</div>
    <div class="card">Card 2</div>
    <div class="card">Card 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="card sticky-el">Sticky 2</div>
    <div class="card">Card 21</div>
    <div class="card">Card 22</div>
    <div class="card">Card 23</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need this.
To achieve the desired effect, you can use a combination of position: fixed and JavaScript to create a similar scrolling effect while keeping the sticky behavior.

```css
.container {
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
  }

  .scroller {
display: flex;
position: relative;
animation: autoScroll 10s linear infinite;
  }

  .card {
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 10px;
width: 70px;
background: lightblue;
  }

  .sticky-el {
width: 100px;
background: cyan;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
  }
  
  @keyframes autoScroll {
0% {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
<div class="scroller" id="scroller1">
  <div class="card sticky-el">Sticky 1</div>
  <div class="card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="card">Card 3</div>
  <!-- Add more cards as needed -->
</div>

<div class="scroller" id="scroller2">
  <div class="card">Card 21</div>
  <div class="card">Card 22</div>
  <div class="card">Card 23</div>
  <div class="card">Card 24</div>
  <!-- Add more cards as needed -->
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually, I am using this in an angular application, and doing it inside animationframe in javascript will have performance issues, and using direct CSS animation would be ideal in my scenario as the list data would be at least 150-200 items.

Comment: @Teja I have updated the code.

Comment: But the first element does not remain sticky to the left. To see the desired result, uncomment the `left` properties in the `@keyframes` and comment out the `transform` property.

Comment: Unfortunately, achieving this behavior purely with CSS, ``without JavaScript``, is not possible due to the specific behavior you're looking for.